# new List on dart (I think give error because i use old one?)

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I'm new to dart and try to learn in some tutorials but when i want create a list gives error to me.

That's the code what i saw in tutorial and it's worked fine

```
void main() {
  var list_name = new List();
}
```

And that's the error

```
'List' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use a list literal, [], or the List.filled constructor instead.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.dartdeprecated_member_use
The default 'List' constructor isn't available when null safety is enabled.
Try using a list literal, 'List.filled' or 'List.generate'.dartdefault_list_constructor
(deprecated) List<dynamic> List([int? length])
dart:core

Creates a list of the given length.

NOTICE: This constructor cannot be used in null-safe code. Use [List.filled] to create a non-empty list. This requires a fill value to initialize the list elements with. To create an empty list, use [] for a growable list or List.empty for a fixed length list (or where growability is determined at run-time).

The created list is fixed-length if [length] is provided.

var fixedLengthList = List(3);
fixedLengthList.length;     // 3
fixedLengthList.length = 1; // Error
The list has length 0 and is growable if [length] is omitted.

var growableList = List();
growableList.length; // 0;
growableList.length = 3;
To create a growable list with a given length, for a nullable element type, just assign the length right after creation:

List<SomeNullableType> growableList = []..length = 500;
For a non-nullable element type, an alternative is the following:

List<int> growableList = List<int>.filled(500, 0, growable: true);
The [length] must not be negative or null, if it is provided.

If the element type is not nullable, [length] must not be greater than zero.
```

Comment: you don't need to use `new` keyword anymore and try newer tutorials and for your question that was older method which you are trying  now `List<type> list_name = <List<type>>[];` if  your want to give type otherwise just do `List list_name = [];`

Comment: thanks, looks like finding a new tutorial is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says to use `[]` to declare a new empty list.
Like this:

```
 var list_name = [];
```

Same thing for `Map`s

```
Map<String,dynamic> _map = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

This constructor ('List()') cannot be used in null-safe code. Use [List.filled] to create a non-empty list. This requires a fill value to initialize the list elements with. To create an empty list, use [] for a growable list or List.empty for a fixed length list (or where growability is determined at run-time).

The created list is fixed-length if [length] is provided.

so I recommend you to use for fixed Length List :

```dart
var lst1 = List.filled(6, 0, growable: false);
lst1[0] = 12;
print(lst1..length) // 6
```

And  use for growable list :

```dart
var lst1 = List.filled(6, 0, growable: true);
lst1[0] = 12;
print(lst1..length) // 6
 
// for adding an item use the add method
lst1.add(4); // add an element to a list
print(lst1.length); // 7
```